# Категории в django

Tags: django

Мне нужно придать элементу класс active, в том случае, если страница на которой находится пользователь отображает продукты текущей категории, сортировка по которой идёт на странице.

Часть кода, который я хочу чтобы работал

Views:

```
def index(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'index.html',
                    {
                        'category': category,
                        'categories': categories,
                        'products': products,
                        'current_category': category.slug
                    })
```

Шаблон HTML

```
{% for category in categories %}
<a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}" class="swiper-slide {% if current_category == category.slug %}active{% endif %}">
<span>{{ category.name }}</span>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нашёл решение данной проблеме